# Change AS Number or add new AS number

Tags: cisco, ripe

We want to change the AS number in our RIPE portal and I want to know we should change the AS number in our Cisco router or we can add new AS number with previous configuration?

My current config:

```
router bgp 202776
 bgp router-id 172.24.124.*
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 172.24.124.* remote-as 43888
 neighbor 172.24.124.* update-source TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 43.*.*.* mask 255.255.254.0
  network 43.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 97.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  neighbor 172.24.124.* activate
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list FROM-ASIATECH in
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list TO-ASIATECH out
 exit-address-family
!
```

Now I want to change router bgp 202776 to

> router bgp 109943

Can I add new config like this?

```
router bgp 202776
 bgp router-id 172.24.124.*
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 172.24.124.* remote-as 43888
 neighbor 172.24.124.* bupdate-source TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 43.*.*.* mask 255.255.254.0
  network 43.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 97.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  neighbor 172.24.124.* activate
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list FROM-ASIATECH in
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list TO-ASIATECH out
 exit-address-family
!

router bgp 109943
bgp router-id 172.24.124.22
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 172.24.124.* remote-as 43888
 neighbor 172.24.124.* update-source TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 43.*.*.* mask 255.255.254.0
  network 43.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 97.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  neighbor 172.24.124.* activate
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list FROM-ASIATECH in
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list TO-ASIATECH out
 exit-address-family
!
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. We can't say anything about your configuration without knowing anything about the configuration or the network topology. You also don't explain *why* you're changing the ASN. Without that information, we can only guess.

Comment: @jesseP. : Thank you, How can I change the current AS number? what are the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your ISP has scheduled when they will be able to do their changes to accommodate your new ASN, you’ll need to plan your changes for the same time to minimize downtime.

You can’t have multiple routing instances for the same protocol, so to change your ASN on your side will require removing the existing configuration and replacing it with the modified configuration.

To remove the existing configuration you will issue the command:

```
no router bgp 202776
```

To add the new configuration you will issue the commands (obviously unmasking your addresses and such as needed):

```
router bgp 109943
bgp router-id 172.24.124.22
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 172.24.124.* remote-as 43888
 neighbor 172.24.124.* update-source TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 43.*.*.* mask 255.255.254.0
  network 43.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 97.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  network 135.*.*.0 mask 255.255.255.0
  neighbor 172.24.124.* activate
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list FROM-ASIATECH in
  neighbor 172.24.124.* prefix-list TO-ASIATECH out
 exit-address-family
!
```

Comment: Thank you, the SSH address of cisco router is in this range: 43.*.*.0 and iam using ssh for configure AS, What will happen for ssh connection after "no router bgp 202776" command?

Comment: @EmmaLee I don’t understand your question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: Can I execute your answer commands with cisco SSH or I should use cisco console?

Comment: @EmmaLee Oh. If you’re accessing the router over the connection that will be altered by changing your BGP statement (for example, if you’re accessing the router from the internet), you should not change the settings that way since you will kill your own connectivity.  If you are accessing the router via SSH privately (like you’re physically at the same location and you’re accessing it from your desk) you will be fine to change the settings via SSH. Otherwise, if you want to be safe, change them via console.